# sql query with a case when returning more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to do a query with a case when condition to see what list I will show but I'm having this error `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`.

the query is this:

```sql
SELECT
CASE WHEN action_type like 'Trigger Severity' THEN (select cast(SEVERITY as varchar2(255)) name from SURV_TRIGGER_SEVERITY_LIST)
     WHEN action_type like 'Host Group'  then (select cast(name as varchar2(255)) name from Surv_List.groups)
     WHEN action_type like 'Host'  then (select cast(name as varchar2(255)) name from tn_tree)
     END display_value
FROM surv_action_type_list
WHERE id = 0
```

is it possible to call a query with more than one row inside a case condition?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Which subquery has multiple rows, and how do you want to handle it?

Comment: Does Oracle really let you select a column name to use in a select statement by querying the column name from another table?

Comment: all the subquerys return multiple rows. I want to chose through the id what list i show to the user.

Comment: I'm not using any column name from another table. My table `surv_action_type_list` is something like this `id =0` `action_type = Host`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this in multiple steps. Get the action type, then issue the appropriate query. Whether you have this logic at the front end or in a stored procedure is up you and probably depends on a lot of other things.

If you absolutely needed to do it this way, then you could try something like this:

```
SELECT
    SQ.display_value
FROM
    surv_action_type_list SATL
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        'Trigger Severity' action_type,
        CAST(severity AS VARCHAR2(255)) display_value
    FROM
        SURV_TRIGGER_SEVERITY_LIST
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'Host Group' action_type,
        CAST(name AS VARCHAR2(255) display_value
    FROM
        Surv_List.groups
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'Host' action_type,
        CAST(name AS VARCHAR2(255) display_value
    FROM
        tn_tree
    ) SQ ON
    SQ.action_type = SATL.action_type
WHERE
    SATL.id = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 sub-queries.

```
1. select cast(SEVERITY as varchar2(255)) name from SURV_TRIGGER_SEVERITY_LIST
2. select cast(name as varchar2(255)) name from Surv_List.groups
3. select cast(name as varchar2(255)) name from tn_tree
```

Each one must return 0 or 1 rows but not more.

Comment: I see that, thats because is giving me the error i put before. I asked if is there is a solution to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No. Your subquery should return only one value (only one row and one column) since you'll display it on a single row.

Since you are displaying the value as one column using your query above, it looks like your intention is to get only one value.

```
select
CASE WHEN action_type like 'Trigger Severity' THEN (select cast(SEVERITY as varchar2(255)) name from SURV_TRIGGER_SEVERITY_LIST)
     WHEN action_type like 'Host Group'  then (select cast(name as varchar2(255)) name from Surv_List.groups)
     WHEN action_type like 'Host'  then (select cast(name as varchar2(255)) name from tn_tree)
    END display_value
from surv_action_type_list
where id = 0
```

Is there a where missing that links this ID to say a Severity list?
Usually queries like this would have a condition in the subquery.. something like..

```
 select
     CASE WHEN action_type like 'Trigger Severity' 
             THEN (select cast(SEVERITY as varchar2(255)) name 
                      **from SURV_TRIGGER_SEVERITY_LIST trglst
                      where trglst.name = lst.severity_name**
     -----
     ---

         END display_value
     from surv_action_type_list lst
    where id = 0
```

Comment: Sorry i have not explained myself well, the subquerys doesnt have any relation with the main query.

Comment: A little set of sample data would certainly help. But the answer to your question is still NO, you cannot get muktiple rows out of each sql in your case.